# login aws ec2 after setting up root passwd

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, root

I set the password for ec2 but after I log out I cannot log back in with my pem file.

```
sudo su
passwd
...

➜  ssh -i /Users/shawn/.ssh/shawn.pem ubuntu@ec2-13-56-168-110.us-west-
1.compute.amazonaws.com                       





Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried

```
ssh -i -vvv /Users/shawn/.ssh/shawn.pem ubuntu@ec2-13-56-168-110.us-west-
1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And I also stop the instance, but still can not log back in.

At the end of the debug mode

```
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 
SHA256:Noh+v+TXrsJV08b9/XFgahk/LDUWBA9Qdozu7oZgcx8
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: did you make any changes to ssh configuration - or just set a password for the root user?

Comment: Just set the password for root user.

Comment: try ssh root@ec2-13-56-168-110.us-west

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-change-root-linux/

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin hi root@ec2... is not working, he would asks me to do ubuntu one.

Comment: you changed into root user "sudo su" then you issed the "passwd" command - this changes the password for current user - if you need to change the password for particular user it's "passwd root" or "passwd ubuntu". If you have not made any changes to sshd.conf then ubuntu user with pem key should still work

Comment: You are wrong. It will change password for root. I have tried to change root password and was able to login. It seems the root of the issue is something else

Answer (score 0):

This is a dead end. Hope other don't make the same mistake as I did before.
If we set up a password for particular user or whatever user. We need to provide public key to the server. And must keep a private key in private. I did unmount the volume and attached to another instance. It still not worked and being considered as some one want to hacked my server. Good Job! 
Amazon EC2.

Comment: My limited understanding is ssh is configured to accept public key authentication only. You can reconfigure ssh to accept password authentication, but you probably shouldn't.